# How to Moq notification for unit test of Mediatr INotificationHandler

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mediator, mediatr

Currently have the following code I am trying to unit test

```
public class EventReceived: INotification{
    public SpecificItems specificItems { get; }
    
    public EventReceived(GenericItem items) {
        foreach(var genericItem in items) {
            specificItems.Add(new SpecificItem(genericItem));
        }
    }
}

public class EventReceivedHandler: INotificationHandler<EventReceived> {
    ....
    public async Task Handle(EventReceived evt) {
        // do some stuff...
    }
}
```

I am trying to test the handle method and need to mock the Event Received evt parameter.  It is a concrete class however and I need to avoid running the constructor logic because it is quite complicated.  Below will run the constructor.

```
_mockEvent = new Mock<EventReceived>
```

I attempted to refactor to the below so I could Moq and interface instead to avoid the constructor logic. **The unit tests work now, however now the event handler does not pick up the firing of the event.**

```
public class EventReceived: IEventReceived {
    public EventReceived(...) {
        // do some stuff...
    }
}

public interface IEventReceived {}

public class EventReceivedHandler : INotificationHandler<IEventReceived> {
    ....
    public async Task Handle(IEventReceived evt) {
        // do some stuff...
    }
}

_mockEvent = new Mock<IEventReceived>
```

What is the recommended way to test these event handlers?  Is there some simple solution I am missing?  I am new to Mediatr.

Comment: Why does the event implement an interface? The only reason for it to implement an interface would be if there's an intent to cast it as that interface. In that case the event handler could depend on an interface, not on a concrete class. Mocking an interface is easier, and then the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only bit you need to test is the `EventReceivedHandler.Handle` method.

If you're using Mediatr, your `EventReceived` class should implement the `INotification` interface.  `EventReceived` should not contain any logic - that should be in `EventReceivedHandler`

Something along these lines:

```
public class EventReceived: INotification {
    public EventReceived()
    {

    }
}



public class EventReceivedHandler: INotificationHandler<EventReceived>
{
    public async Task Handle(EventReceived evt){
        //do some stuff...
    }
}


[TestFixture]
public class EventReceivedHandlerTests 
{
    [Test]
    public async Task DoesSomeStuff()
    {
        //arrange
        //(insert mocked interfaces to handler if required)
        var eventHandler = new EventReceivedHandler();
        var evt = new EventReceived();

        //act
        await eventHandler.Handle(evt);

        //assert
        //.......
    }
}
```

Comment: So my problem is I need to Moq the EventReceived so it returns specific things.  I also don't want the EventReceived constructor to run as there's complex logic in it.  So I attempting to refactor the EventReceived to implement an IEventReceived interface so I could moq the interface.

Comment: Sounds like you need to re-think the design. The EventReceived shouldn't contain any logic. It should be a 'DTO' - all the logic should happen in the Handler, not the message / event.

Comment: Hmmm... the way we have it coded all INotifications take in a generic item and put back out a specific item.  Like so...

```
public class EventReceived: INotification{
 public List<SpecificItem> specificItems {get;}

public EventReceived(IEnumerable<GenericItem> items){
    foreach (var item in items){
   specificItems .Add(new SpecificItem(genericItem))
} 
}
}
```
each notification has it's own specific item that it holds and the notification handler works with the specific items.  Would you suggest making the notification hold the generic items and convert them in the handler?

Comment: You've tagged Mediatr in your question - are you definitely using the Mediatr library?

Comment: Sorry didn't realize it wouldn't format the code.  I edited my original post to give more detail on what the constructor logic is.

I am converting generic items into specific items in the INotification.  Each notification has it owns specific item.  and then the INotificationHandlers work in terms of specific items.  Would you suggest refactoring to have the INotification hold the GenericItems and convert to specific items in the handlers?

Comment: Yes definitely using mediatr, but this is the first project I have used it on.  I had not heard before that the INotification should just be a DTO.

Comment: that 'foreach' should happen in whatever is `.Publish` your event